# Fcntl () function

Tags: filesystems

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int val;

        if(argc!=2)
        {
                printf("Usage: %s <descriptor> \n", argv[0]);
                exit(1);
        }

        val=fcntl(atoi(argv[1]), F_GETFL, 0);


        switch(val & O_ACCMODE)
        {
                case O_RDONLY:
                        printf("read only");
                        break;
                case O_WRONLY:
                        printf("write only");
                        break;
                case O_RDWR:
                        printf("read write");
                        break;
                default:
                        printf("unknown access mode");
        }

        if(val & O_APPEND)
                printf(", append");
        if(val & O_NONBLOCK)
                printf(", nonblocking");
        if(val & O_SYNC)
                printf(", synchronous writes");

        putchar('\n');
        exit(0);
 }
```

in the command line input why i have to specify

```
$./a.out 0 </dev/tty
$./a.out 1 > temp
```

even though fcntl is checking only argument 1 .
pl somebody explain why i have to pass a file with redirection symbol in command line argument.

Comment: Because that's the easiest way to get access to a non-trivial open file descriptor given by its number.  The alternative is to `open(2)` something instead of passing a number.

Comment: @SatoKatsura:  That's a pretty good reason.  You should probably make an answer to explain your logic a little bit more.